# Android tablet booting issue (Sanei n80)

Tags: boot

I bought Sanei N80 android tablet two months back(android 2.3).I tried to root using z4root app.It stuck in the middle so i switched off and switched on the tablet.Now the tablet is not booting up stays in the splash screen (refer attached screenshot1.png). I also tried to reboot it using recovery mode, again its stuck and displaying warning icon with android image (refer attached screenshot2.png). I am pasting the logs for reference.

Kindly please please please help.I don't know how to proceed.

Log, while normal booting.

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 1309): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 1309): CheckJNI is OFF
D/dalvikvm( 1309): creating instr width table
D/dalvikvm( 1309): DexOpt: incorrect opt magic number (0xff ff ff ff)
D/dalvikvm( 1309): ODEX file is stale or bad; removing and retrying (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm( 1309): Zip inflate: partial write (will retry): (4056 of 32768)
E/dalvikvm( 1309): Zip inflate: write failed: No space left on device
E/dalvikvm( 1309): Unable to extract+optimize DEX from '/system/framework/framework.jar'
D/dalvikvm( 1309): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/framework.jar'
E/JNIHelp ( 1309): Native registration unable to find class 'android/debug/JNITest'
E/AndroidRuntime( 1309): Unable to register all android natives
I/ServiceManager( 79): service 'media.camera' died
I/ServiceManager(79): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
I/ServiceManager( 79): service 'media.player' died
I/ServiceManager( 79): service 'media.audio_policy' died
I/Netd ( 1311): Netd 1.0 starting
I/ (1310): ServiceManager: 0xacb0
E/AudioHardware( 1310): Can't load libsecril-client.so
D/AudioHardwareInterface( 1310): setMode(NORMAL)
I/CameraService( 1310): CameraService started (pid=1310)
I/AudioFlinger( 1310): AudioFlinger's thread 0xc7b8 ready to run
D/AudioHardware( 1310): AudioStreamOutALSA::setParameters() routing=2
D/AudioHardware( 1310): ### setVoiceVolume_l
```

[screen shot one](http://i1255.photobucket.com/albums/hh622/rsiyer/screenshot1.png)

[Screen shot two](http://i1255.photobucket.com/albums/hh622/rsiyer/screenshot1.png)

Comment: The screenshots didn't come through.  I suggest hosting them somewhere (photobucket.com for example) and then posting links to the pictures here.

Comment: I have posted the screenshots

Answer (score 1):

z4root is for android version 2.2, as versions such as honeycomb have such methods of rooting patched. Try a hard reset.

Comment: I did it mistakenly :( any other way to make it boot again.

Comment: So do you still want to root your device?

Comment: No, i don't want to root it again.I need to make it work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I've updated my answer.